# Get event outside the iframe or reload the main website from iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am opening an url in iframe. That page has form to fill by user. When user fill the form, I want to reload the main website (outside the iframe) to be reload. Or if I can trigger a outside javascript function with in iframe.

I am working with ReactJs.

Ex. I have 2 Websites A and B. I am opening a specific url of site B in A using iframe. When user submit the form in ifram. I want to reload the web page of site A using javascript. When I try window.location.reload(), window.parent.location.reload(). they all reload iframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954454/how-to-reload-main-page-from-within-an-iframe/22933484

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

and just adding the url of the original page? window.location.reload() is just refreshing the page, so if you open a new page refreshing it is still going to keep you on that page.

Comment: I tried it and getting following error:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Javascript don't allow to access cross origin.

Comment: Maybe try something like `document.domain ="url.html";` and see if that works